# the nhibernate cross machine lazy load problem

Tags: c#, wcf, fluent-nhibernate, lazy-loading

i got a client a server and a db
db mapped to server with fluent nhibernate.
so far so good
the client talks with the server with wcf.
i want to implement lazy loading on client side.

is there any solution out there?

Comment: FYI stackoverflow isn't a place for people to write code for you, you're asking a very complex question. assuming people do answer you for a question of this complexity expect to receive lots of information most likely pointing to other SO posts and blogs that will help you develop the answer yourself. This is a non trival problem, you shouldn't expect someone to be able to hand you code you can copy and paste into your solution with no changes. It's possible this is more of a language barrier but telling others "give me a good solution" is not conducive to getting help.

Comment: i just need the link i couldn't find myself i'm not asking for someone to do the job for me.... i'm sure someone already did it thats all..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no solution for that, lazy loading works with nhibernate's proxy mechanism which is very intrinsic to its implementation.
there was one project called [Nhibernate.Remote](http://slagd.com/) but this has been abandoned. 
nhibernate would work over wcf, but without lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

The nature of WCF would be to learn towards your data being shaped prior to sending, ie., it's already been retreived and put into a datacontract of some sort.

Possibly you could provide a parameter on the inital service call to indicate whether child properties should be populated, although how far you go is always going to be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

when i realized that it can't happen, i decided to work with the projection and the result transformer.

it works good.

if i need to load some lazy loading collection i just iterate it on server and send it back to client,
when i wanna update a partially selected object i have to reselect him from db and update the full data entity.

but it's worth it

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to be pessimistic but making NHibernate work with lazy loading over WCF is **NOT GOING TO WORK**.

Comment: i understand you positions but the other fellows here posted some nice links with stuff that work.. but not good enougth for enterprise applications...

Answer (score 0):

With the below code WCF can work with lazy loading:

```
var proxy = myObj as INHibernateProxy;
myObj = (myObj)proxy.HibernateLazyInitializer.GetImplementation();
```